# How to display some settings for super admin user only using Settings API

Tags: options, settings-api

I'm developing a plugin with an options page using the Settings API.

I'd like to have one options array stored for my plugin, but on the settings page, I'd only like some of the settings to be visible to admin users, but the full list of settings to be available to the super admin.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the current user’s role with `current_user_can( 'administrator' )`:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )
{
    add_settings_field( /* arguments */ );
    // or
    add_settings_section( /* arguments */ );
}
```

Make sure to use the same check when you save the options. Otherwise your regular users might delete the values.

Comment: I'm not sure that this would play nicely with `do_settings_sections()`, unless administrator-only settings were given their own settings section.

Comment: The callback for `do_settings_fields()` can include that test.

Comment: Ooooh, that would be nicely elegant! Though, it might work even better in the `add_settings_field()` callback.

Comment: Thanks @toscho -- I've got the display working correctly now! Where would you suggest I do the check when I save the options.. in the callback specified in `register_setting()`?

Comment: Also, if I'm using `do_settings_fields()` instead of `do_settings_sections()` -- I take it that I need to manually print the section titles and the table opening and closing tags, correct? Or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: @jessica See my update: It depends on how you organized the fields.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Look at the source of `do_settings_sections()` in `wp-admin/includes/template.php`.

Comment: I have this fully implemented now, thank you. I should note it's not necessary to use `do_settings_fields()` instead of `do_settings_sections()` if the admin-only settings section is added conditionally, as you described in your edited answer. To make sure options weren't overwritten, in the sanitize callback, I got the old values and looped through them, checking to see if each key exists in the newly submitted value. If the key doesn't exist, I set it in the new values array before returning it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could incorporate `current_user_can()` into the `add_settings_field()` callback for each admin-only option:

```
function somesetting_add_settings_field( $option ) {
    // This is an admin-only option
    if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) {
        // If current user is admin,
        // output the form field
    } else {
        // Otherwise, output a message,
        // or display a static value of the option,
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Using this method, you shouldn't have to mess with your actual settings page markup at all.

If your sanitization callback is written properly, such that you check for data to be set, and array_merge() validated/sanitized values with existing option values, you shouldn't have to worry about any admin-only settings being deleted or improperly overwritten.

Comment: It seems like this solution wouldn't output any editable fields for non admin users, amirite?

Comment: Oh, are you saying to only include this callback for the admin-only settings, and use a different callback for the settings available to regular users?

Comment: Each setting uses its own callback. If you build things dynamically using an array of arrays of options, then just add an `admin-only` option parameter, and test for it with the `current_user_can()` conditional.

Comment: Cheers, this would also work. However, I think I'm going with @toscho's answer because I believe it'd take less code to just conditionally add the admin-only settings section. I wouldn't have to change the markup with that solution either (not sure why he mentioned using 'do_settings_fields()' in the comments, as it turns out it isn't necessary).